# Why use another person Docker Image?

Tags: docker

I'm learning about Docker architecture.

I know that images are made to run applications in containers (virtualization). One thing that I stepped on was that there is an entire community hub for posting images. But what is actually the point of doing that?

Isn't the idea of images contain a very specific enviroment with very specific configurations that runs very specific applications?

Comment: Images are not as static as they may seem at first. We can make them configurable through environment variables and volume mounts (especially configuration files). And as was pointed out by kutschenk in their answer, images are building blocks. Typical scenario: For a web application, we want ot have a database and an OIDC provider. For this, we can use a `postgres`- and a `keycloak`-container, grouped together in a `docker-compose.yml` to start our dev environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of images is to have a well-defined environment. The images by the community serve mostly as building blocks or base images for your own, more specific, images. For some applications, you can use an image as-is with maybe a little configuration parameters, but I would guess the more common use case is to start building your specific image based on an already existing, more general image.

Example:

- You want to create an image with a certain Java application. So you look for an image that already has the Java version you want, and create an image based on that more general image.
- You want to test your application on different OS versions (maybe different Linux versions). So you create a couple of images, each based on a different base image that already has the OS installed that you are interested in.